# OpenLayers Multiple Maps Problem (maps leave blank)

Tags: openlayers-2, maps

I try a round with OpenLayers and was very impressed how mighty it is.

But I have a problem (maybe a easy one, because I am not so trained in js).

After adding additional maps all maps leave blank, and I don't know why. Maybe I need a simple hind

```
    <script src="http://openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js" ></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var supplyMap, demandMap, voluminaMap;
    var supplyMapLayer, demandMapLayer, voluminaMapLayer;
    var supplyMapMarkers, demandMapMarkers, voluminaMapMarkers;

    function init(){
        var wms_all = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("OpenLayers WMS", "http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0", {layers: 'basic'});

        //set supplyMap
        supplyMap = new OpenLayers.Map('supplyMap', {});
        supplyMapLayer = wms_all.clone();
        supplyMapMarkers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers( "SupplyMarkers" );

        supplyMap.addLayers([supplyMapLayer, supplyMapMarkers]);
        supplyMap.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(10.5,51.25),6.5);

        //set demandMap
        demandMap = new OpenLayers.Map('demandMap', {});
        demandMapLayer = wms_all.clone();
        demandMapMarkers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers( "DemandMarkers" );

        demandMap.addLayers([supplyMapLayer, supplyMapMarkers]);
        demandMap.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(10.5,51.25),6.5);

        //set voluminaMap
        voluminaMap = new OpenLayers.Map('voluminaMap', {});
        voluminaMapLayer = wms_all.clone();
        voluminaMapMarkers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers( "VoluminaMarkers" );

        voluminaMap.addLayers([voluminaMapLayer, voluminaMapMarkers]);
        voluminaMap.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(10.5,51.25),6.5);




       // setMarker(52.519945, 13.404713);
       // setMarker(48.141176, 11.568800);      

    }

  function setMarker(lat, lon){

        var markerVal = new OpenLayers.LonLat(lon, lat);
        var size      = new OpenLayers.Size(21,25);
        var offset    = new OpenLayers.Pixel(-(size.w/2), -size.h);
        var icon      = new OpenLayers.Icon('http://www.openlayers.org/dev/img/marker.png',size,offset); 

        markers.addMarker(new OpenLayers.Marker(markerVal,icon.clone()));  

  }

  function clearMarker(){
       markers.clearMarkers();
  }



  </script>                                       
    <style>
      @media screen
      {
        .supplyMap{width: 850px; height: 725px; border: 2px solid black;}
        .demandMap{width: 850px; height: 725px; border: 2px solid black;}
        .voluminaMap{width: 850px; height: 725px; border: 2px solid black;}
      }
    </style>
```